# Modal dialog disposal

Tags: wxpython

I tried wxPython for the first time with a hitherto console-only program running in xterm to pop up a trivial confirmation dialog in the X11/KDE environment of a Debian box.  If wx is detected (import wx succeeds), my script uses this function to ask simple yes/no questions:

```
def md (prompt='Continue or cancel'):
    wa = wx.App()
    confd = wx.MessageDialog(None,prompt,'YND',
                             wx.OK | wx.CANCEL | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
    confr = confd.ShowModal()
    return confr == wx.ID_OK
```

This behaves as expected/desired, presenting the dialog and detecting the input correctly.  But the window persists after use.  It does not disappear until the Python script ends.  I've tried myriad ways to understand the behavior and determine the proper/accepted/canonical way to make the window disappear when appropriate without success.  The only partial success occurs if I call showModal() again subsequently, in which case the window is replaced with a new dialog - obviously not an acceptable solution.

Hoping someone will see some obviously boneheaded error on my part before I start looking at tkinter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated- tested on windows 10, wxpython 4.1a, python 3.6.8**

You have an interesting use-case for wx. Dialogs by design aren't destroyed when they're closed. You have to explicitly call `Destroy()` or use them in a context manager (which calls destroy on exit). Here's two examples that attempt to fix your issue:

```
import wx


def md_1(prompt="Continue or cancel"):
    ret_code = [None]

    def show_dialog():
        with wx.MessageDialog(frame, prompt, 'YND', wx.OK | wx.CANCEL | wx.ICON_QUESTION) as dialog:
            ret_code[0] = dialog.ShowModal()
        frame.Close()

    app = wx.App()

    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    wx.CallAfter(show_dialog)
    app.MainLoop()
    return ret_code[0] == wx.ID_OK


def md_2(prompt="Continue or cancel"):
    app = wx.App()

    with wx.MessageDialog(None, prompt, 'YND', wx.OK | wx.CANCEL | wx.ICON_QUESTION) as dialog:
        ret = dialog.ShowModal()
    app.Destroy()
    return ret == wx.ID_OK


if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = md_1()
    input("answer #1 was {0}".format(answer))
    answer = md_2()
    input("answer #2 was {0}".format(answer))
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your explanation comports with my assumptions about how it should work, and I had earlier tried to explicitly Destroy() the dialog.  I also tried other things such as executing del on the dialog and/or the app ref, to no avail.  I also assumed that this would be superfluous because exiting md() ought to deallocate the objects due to unreferencing and accordingly, the with block is gratuitous.

Anyway, your sample code behaves the same way on my system; the dialog persists until after the input() executes and the script exits.  Something must be different from your environment.

Comment: @BillMichaelson  interesting, which OS are you using? What happens if you add `wx.Exit()` before the `return` statement?

Comment: wx.Exit() takes the dialog down, but it takes the process down too.  It's Debian Buster with kernel 4.19.0-6-amd64, wxPython built with GTK3, I think.

What are you running it on?

Comment: @BillMichaelson I updated my answer to include 2 variations of the function that  will hopefully solve your problem

Comment: I infer that these functions only work properly in the context of the full framework that uses the event processing wx.App.MainLoop().  Thus using CallAfter() to inject the dialog presentation into such processing is required.  Seems reasonable, although ideally, one would see it fail earlier when attempting to present a dialog as I had.

At least, that is, in my environment - because md_1() in your revision works satisfactorily for me now.  The earlier version shown as md_2 does not.  Thanks much!

Comment: @BillMichaelson md_2 added `app.Destroy()` as opposed to `wx.Exit()`